# How to implement a self sizing UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I want to dynamically resize my UITableView based on its content. As an UITableView has no intrinsic content size, I have to manipulate the height constraint programmatically. However, I want to have a `max_height` after which the UITableView stops growing.

With each reload, I set the UITableView's height constraint to its contentSize. If the contentSize is bigger than what fits into the defined boundaries, AutoLayout complains it "can not satisfy constraints simultaneously".  So I tried giving the UITableView's height constraint the priority 999. In my understanding, if AutoLayout has to break constraints, it breaks the ones with the lowest priority first and tries to get as close to the constant as possible. (Perfect!)

If everything above the TableView is of fixed height, this works fine as seen in:

[image]

As soon as anything above the TableView relies on intrinsic contentSize (like a StackView with two labels) it doesn't work anymore. As soon as the height constraint gets too big, anything without a fixed height gets compressed. (Setting the compression resistance to 751 and content hugging priority to 249 does not change this)

[image]

To make it easier to verify I have created a GitHub project (https://github.com/Shanakor/SelfSizing-TableView/branches). On branch "master" you will find the working copy and on branch "not_working" you will find the alternative approach.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Even after your change in Question description the reason is in constraints' priorities. Your `stackview` height is defined from its' intrinsic size. Which in turn is defined according to intrinsic sizes or height constraints of the arranged views (in this case it's intrinsic size of labels). So if you want your stack view to keep it's size (i.e. resist compression), the priority of the compression resistance(of the stack view and all its' arranged views) should be higher than the priority of table view height constraint.

So you need to set **table view height constraint** priority lower than `UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh` (i.e. at least 749) and the default compression resistance for the stackView

Comment: But then it will override the constraint (>= 16). I do not want that. When the TableView reaches its maximum height it should stop growing.

Comment: If you didn't change the priority of (>=16) constraint, its' priority is `UILayoutPriorityRequired` so it won't be overridden. In other case, add your constraints' priorities to your question and I'll try to help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My TableViewHeightConstraint has priority 999. All others have priority 1000.

Comment: As I understand it Autolayout will try to drop the height constraint, as soon as it gets too big, right? So this leaves me with an inconsistent layout.

Comment: Autolayout won't just drop it. It'll still take it into account to calculate the height for table view, but in case the constraint could not be satisfied along with required constraints, it'll be taken into account in the last order. I.e. (>=16) constraint doesn't actually set the distance between bottom edge and button but together with other constraints including tableview height it becomes clear what that distance should be

Comment: @Shanakor Did you set the height constraint for your Add button? Or did you change its' compression resistance priority? Because it should have higher priority than the priority of the table view height constraint or the button will become zero-sized before tableview height will be limited

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstions. Tomorrow I will edit the question with much more details. I think I did a terrible job describing my problem.

Comment: @Shanakor I downloaded your example and it proved my suggestion - what you need is to fix constraint priority. Check out my edited answer